# Create Excel using openxml with embed css

Tags: css, excel, c#-4.0, openxml

In my web application, i'm using openXML to create and export excel files.

but i'm using different theme. so i want to change my excels style sheets base on my themes.

as far as i know this is how you can set the foreground Color of a cell in open xml:

```
ForegroundColor foregroundColor1 = new ForegroundColor() { Rgb = "FFFF0000" };
```

but i don't want to hard code my color.
So here is my question: is there anyway to use embed css for colorize my excel content using openXml?

thank you all

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb508298(v=office.15).aspx) page (MSDN) will be of use to you. Talks about Theme replacement.

Comment: @ boxed__l : thank you for your reply.but it seems it's only for word not excel :(